# MongoDB findOne multiple query fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, koa

Bad way (works directly):

```
user =
    yield users.findOne({
        'profile.personal.email': email
    });
if(user === null) {
    user =
        yield users.findOne({
            'profile.company.email': email
        });
}
```

I would like something like this:

```
user =
    yield users.findOne({
        'profile.personal.email': email,
        'profile.company.email': email
    });
```

The above returns null. I would like to require the first match of any of the two fields above. I'm pretty sure mongodb can do this. I would like *or* not *and*. So if either of the emails are found it should return the document.

I'm using Koajs with co-monk module. i can use aggregration if it's required.

Answer (score 4):

Remembered the `$or` operator:

```
user =
    yield users.findOne({
        $or: [{
            'profile.personal.email': email
        }, {
            'profile.company.email': email
        }]
    });
```